# Showing the current SharePoint server data and time under login username on the upper right corner

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, page-layout

A requirement has been issued to display the current server Date and time under the username on the right left corner of the SharePoint application. Can anyone advice on how I can do this ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

i added the following currentdate Div tag to my master page below the welcome div:-

```
<div id="suiteBarRight">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteBarRight" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteBarRight" BlockElement="true">
<div id="welcomeMenuBox">
<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
  <div id="currentdate"></div>
```

Then i added a Script editor web part to my page as follow:-

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var days = date.getDay(); 
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
var strTime = date ;
return strTime;
}
</script>
```

but the result is that the date will be shown very close to the user name on IE as follow:-

[image]

while it will be out of the layout on Firefox as follow:-

[image]

any idea how i can improve the layout for the date?

thanks

Comment: You do know that this will display the client date, not the server date, right?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by Server Data? and Why would you need the time below the user's info!

Comment: sorry i mean the server date not data ! i need to display the current date and time below the login username. can you check my update and what i have tried so far.